# Passing pointer to int in LUA FFI

Tags: ffi, luajit

I have a C function as follows

ffi.cdef[[

```
typedef struct {
    int index;
    char name[10];
} entry_key_t;

extern entry_t *lookup_entry(entry_key_t *key, int *err);
```

]]

I am having trouble passing the "int *" and I have tried the following variants,

local err_val = ffi.new("int[1]")
local err_val = ffi.new("int *")

The program crashes as the "err" passed to the function is NULL. (Pls note that I am able to pass pointer 'key' after doing ffi.new("entry_key_t[1]"))

What am I missing? I am using LuaJIT 2.0.2.

Comment: `local err_Val=ffi.new("int[1]")` should work. Perhaps you're doing something wrong, e.g. dereferencing the pointer while passing it to the function? Note that ffi.new without initializer will init the pointer to 0. Please post the code up to the point when you invoke `lookup_entry`

Comment: Sorry, it a stupid typo in my code. And yes local err_Val=ffi.new("int[1]") and intPtr() (Per the answer from Alex) worked. Sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure this will work for you but the pattern I've used for out params is:

```
local intPtr = ffi.typeof"int[1]"

local key = ffi.new("entry_key_t[1]")
local err = intPtr()

lookup_entry(key,err)

print(err[0])
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But the issue was a stupid typo in the code and I think I was drunk to catch it ;-)